# Automatic Application Update in Citrix Environment

Tags: c#, auto-update, citrix, terminal-services

I have an application I Am developing that will be installed into a Citrix Server Farm environment where multiple Users will connect using Citrix XenApp.  I want to incorporate ['](https://wyday.com/wybuild/) into the application so that when a User runs up the application it will check for updates and prompt the User to update the application.

I have some uncertainties about this, specifically what considerations I need to make when installing my application on Citrix, e.g. If User A (and many other Users) is in the application and User B launches the application and gets prompted to update how will should this get handled if the application is installed in Program Files where it typically should be installed?

- Should I install the application in Program Files and "shadow copy" to the User directory for execution?
- Should I install the Application per user when each User first logs in?
- Or are there other considerations to be made?

Hope someone has encountered this and can help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to install the application per user when each user first logs in.  In this way, when a user starts the app, it will update that user's copy and you will avoid file locks that will happen when a second user starts the app when it is being updated.

Comment: Ok, so where would I go about installing files on a "Per User" install?